# Test failure: Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, testing, minitest

I'm a newbie to rails and starting with setting up my first testing suite.

In my tests I keep getting the following failure:

```
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

This response is odd, as the redirect clearly works when testing using the browser. Does anyone have an idea what could be going on here, or what is the best approach in diagnosing such problem. For example, is there a way to find out on what page the 200 message was given.

The test script (user_controller_test.rb)

```
test "when correct should redirect to dashboard" do
    log_in_as(@user_one)
    assert_redirected_to dashboard_url
end
```

The full console message

```
 FAIL["test_should_get_dashboard_when_correct_user", UsersControllerTest, 2015-12-23 18:06:20 +1100]
 test_should_get_dashboard_when_correct_user#UsersControllerTest (1450854380.57s)
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

The controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

          log_in user         
          params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
          redirect_back_or dashboard
     else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new' 
    end
  end
```

Comment: I think something is different between your controller test and manual testing in browser.

Comment: What is the content of the page that you get back with 200? Inspect it and it might lead you to a solution.

Comment: Can you add your controller / action?

Comment: The source code of your test would help us to investigate an issue.

Comment: Are you doing the redirect via JavaScript?

Comment: Not sure how to diagnose what is the difference between the controller test and the manual test. How do I check to content of the 200 page? Just posted the controller action. No javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a faulty test.

This is what the code in your controller says:

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  redirect_back_or dashboard
else
  render 'new' 
end

# if user is not nil AND user can authenticate with given params
  # success (redirect)
# else the params passed to the controller did not authenticate the user
  # fail (render 200)
```

Then your test says:

```
log_in_as(@user_one)
assert_redirected_to dashboard_url

# login user manually, rather than assign params
# check if the controller action redirected, meaning check if it could authenticate with the given params that you did not assign
```

See the problem? You need to set the params that the controller action is checking if you want it to pass the `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what it is. I should not expect a redirect, as it is the controller action (create) and not the method login_in_as that initiates the redirect.